# Sending an hyperlink by mail removes the hyperlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

In C#, When sending a confirmation email with a link to the confirmation page, the hyperlink part is removed from the text, leaving only the string.

Here is the code I use :

```
using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
            {
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress("qreftrain@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(user.Email);
                mail.Subject = "QuidditchRefTraining Subscription";
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("qreftrain@gmail.com", "password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                try
                {
                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                }
```

With the body having this value :

```
"<html><body>blabla : <a href='localhost:45398/Login/ConfirmEmail?Code=a13c444fba0a45b69009ba167a7e4a82&RequestId=15' title='User Email Confirm'>Lien</a>.</body></html>"
```

I get an email looking like this (disregard the line before "Lien", it's french) :

[image]

with the word Lien being a simple word. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Just to debug, reaplce your linke with something that starts with https, and also drop the title part from your link, lets see what you get.

Comment: @PiJei Yes ! Thank you ! It was the missing https at the beginning of the link. How do I give you karma ?

Comment: Great! you are welcome, you could click on the triangle next to my comment!